# Save high-quality {DiagrammeR} node graph

Tags: r, svg, plot, save, diagrammer

I've made a node graph with {DiagrammeR} and need to save it in high-quality for publication, but none of the usual high-quality saving methods work (e.g. ggsave() -naturally-, svg(), png(), etc.)

No need to upload the whole code, but the two final lines (should suffy) are the following:

```
graph <- create_graph(nodes_df = nodes, edges_df = 
render_graph(graph)
```

Does anybody know how can I do it? I've tried simply exporting it as .png in the viewer panel and vectorize it online, but couldn't get the quality I want (though if anybody knows of a very good free only vectorizer, grateful to hear it).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a way in export_graph: `export_graph(graph, file_name = "filename.svg")` from the same `DiagrammeR` package. You can also choose .png and other formats.